# Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching "App Name"

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, code-signing, provisioning-profile

I am trying to build flutter with one of XCode's simulators but it is giving me this error in the general tab of Runner Xcode

> couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching
>   "App Name"

also the build fails with this error:

> ld: library not found for -lFMDB

is it possible to run ios without enrolling to apple developer plans(also is it possible to build IPAs this way?)

Comment: This is probably not a `flutter` or `dart` issue per-set. It appears that you do not have the property Provisioning Profile set up to deploy your app to a Simulator. I would recommend reading up on https://developer.apple.com/support/code-signing/. The IFMDB linker error is a separate issue.

Answer (score 0):

Running a Flutter app on an iOS simulator doesn't require an Apple Developer account, unless you need to have some [Capabilities](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/adding_capabilities_to_your_app) enabled in the iOS app for example. If you're using Android Studio, you can run the Flutter app on an iOS simulator easily after it has been [set up](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#set-up-the-ios-simulator).

[image: Android Studio Flutter iOS Simulator]

Comment: Couldn't you also just open the simulator, then select the safari app, and navigate to the flutter PWA-style app?

Comment: @John Running the app for web, that should be possible.